# Verify group ID's, with varying row counts, have the same value in columns B and D

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Good afternoon, before even reading this thank you for taking a look.

I have a unique situation and was wondering if anyone could help me out with creating a macro to assist me.

[image]

I have 4 columns:
(Column A) Group ID
(Column B) Spaces/Homes
(Column C) Occupied
(Column D) Park Name

I am manually reviewing each Group ID (Column A) and ensuring that columns B and D have matching values. I was wondering if it is possible to write a macro that will check each group ID and ensure that both columns B and D have matching values.

In this example picture, you will see that group ID 1 has four entries. I have highlighted it in yellow because two entries have column B as 100+ and two entries have column B as 200. This needs to be flagged by highlighting or something on the group ID so I can go in and manually review the entry and see which is the accurate entry.
You will also see group ID 3 has four entries. Here column B matches; however, column D does not. The second entry has the name 'Elcer II.' That needs to be flagged because all Column D values in group ID 3 do not match. So, in all, I need a way of checking that each group ID has the same column B value and column D value.

Is this possible? Even if I have to run two separate macros - one for checking group ID and column B value and one for checking group ID and column D value.

Thank you so much!!!! It has been a hassle trying to do this manually.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple conditional formatting do?

Comment: My VBA skills are not broad enough to even attempt to make this happen. I have scoured through the internet trying to find a way. I have come across multiple possible solutions but have had no success.  This post here I spent an hour trying to get to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035600/vba-search-for-corresponding-line-and-compare-values

Comment: I have tried conditional formatting unique values but I have no way of focusing on the group ID. Unless I am missing something. That is why I have come to StackOverflow for help.

Comment: Tim!  You are the man.  Thank you so much. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the ID list starting from A2, then add a formula-based Conditional Formatting rule using the formula

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A,A2)<>COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,$B2,$D:$D,$D2)
```

Comment: Tim! You are the man. Thank you so much. This worked perfectly.